# Delete certain rows based on columns

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a data.frame as below:

```
SNP             A1      A2      EFF                     FRQ
rs12565286      C       G       -0.00225985777786465    .04354
rs11804171      A       T       -0.00530020318295282    .04485
rs3094315       C       T       -0.0042551489236695     .8364
rs12562034      A       G       -0.00911972489527125    .09763
rs12124819      G       A       0.0250148724382224      .7744
rs2980319       A       T       0.0178927256033542      .1306
rs4040617       A       G       -0.0173263263037023     .8707
```

I would like to delete any row that has an A1-A2 pair of C-G, G-C, A-T, or T-A.

For example, since the first line has a A1 = C and a A2 = G, I would like to delete that row. I would also like to delete the second row because it is a A-T pair. The third row is an AG pair which is fine so I would like to keep it.

My desired output:

```
    SNP             A1      A2      EFF                     FRQ
    rs3094315       C       T       -0.0042551489236695     .8364
    rs12562034      A       G       -0.00911972489527125    .09763
    rs12124819      G       A       0.0250148724382224      .7744
    rs4040617       A       G       -0.0173263263037023     .8707
```

Comment: To exclude ambiguous SNPs, have a look [snpflip](https://github.com/endrebak/snpflip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!(A1=="C" & A2 == "G" | A1 == "G" & A2 == "C" | A1 == "A" & A2 == "T" | A1== "T" & A2 == "A"))
         SNP A1 A2          EFF     FRQ
1  rs3094315  C  T -0.004255149 0.83640
2 rs12562034  A  G -0.009119725 0.09763
3 rs12124819  G  A  0.025014872 0.77440
4  rs4040617  A  G -0.017326326 0.87070
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new_df <- old_df[which(old_df$A1!='C' & old_df$A2!='G' | old_df$A1!='G'& old_df$A2!='C'),]
```

edit : did not see not equal to 
edit : excluded AT and TA ,as this would give enough to tackle further cases

Comment: This does not return the correct result. You should be using `&` and `|` not  `&&` and `||`, but it would still be incorrect after that.

Comment: I understand the && ,|| mistake but why would it be incorrect if & and I is used instead

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: "& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector"

Comment: It still wouldn't work because they would all be true.  Take it apart and look at just the result from `old_df$A1!='C' & old_df$A2!='G' | old_df$A1!='G' & old_df$A2!='C'`

Comment: @JacobH I excluded AT and TA ,as I thought my answer would give enough to tackle further cases .

Comment: @Bg1850 you need to make this line of thinking explicit in your answer.  Otherwise your answer is incomplete/confusing.

Comment: Nice, you might also consider removing the call to `which`.

Comment: Yes I agree that using which is redundant ,but is there a reason that which exists or any performance gain may be in large data frames that you are aware of

Comment: There is no performance gain from `which` AFIK.  The `which` function can come in handy some times, but for the majority of cases I find that it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I like this approach because it does not require numerous `|` and `&` calls which I find annoying.  That being said, I would imagine that other approaches would run faster.

```
r <- c("C", "G", "A", "T")
l <- c("G", "C", "T", "A")

df[!(paste0(df$A1, df$A2) %in% paste0(r,l)), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `dplyr` method, building a little off of @JacobH and @DatamineR's answers.

This data.frame is defined in *R* but, if larger and/or requiring other inputs, could be handled elsewhere (spreadsheet?) and read into this format.

```
removeDF <- data.frame(A1=c('C','G','A','T'),
                       A2=c('G','C','T','A'),
                       REMOVE=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The `REMOVE` variable is simply something to indicate if a row was successfully merged (i.e., needing to be removed).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    left_join(removeDF, by=c('A1','A2')) %>%
    filter(is.na(REMOVE)) %>%
    select(-REMOVE)
##          SNP A1 A2          EFF     FRQ
## 1  rs3094315  C  T -0.004255149 0.83640
## 2 rs12562034  A  G -0.009119725 0.09763
## 3 rs12124819  G  A  0.025014872 0.77440
## 4  rs4040617  A  G -0.017326326 0.87070
```

This is close to a dplyr-version of @JacobH's answer, but offers a different format for defining the pairs-to-be-removed. (His is roughly 8x faster with larger datasets.)